# How do I get real path of a folder inside static block of a class

Tags: java

I have a web app and I need to get absolute path of a folder (in my case, WEB-INF) in a static block of a class which is not a servlet. Of course, I could take this value from properties file but can I do this otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean by "real path of a folder"?

Comment: Do you have a reason for _not_ using a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getRealPath() method of the ServletContext ServletContext.getRealPath to find out the actual folder in your filesystem like

```
String realPathOfImgFolder=req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/foldername");
```

You may not get the WEB-INF folder name like this because it is not in the servlet context's exposed directories, you may have to do something like this for it

```
String rootPath=req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File webInfFolder=new File(rootPath,"WEB-INF");
```

[EDIT] If you dont have the `request` object, then you will have to  use a `ServletContextListener` and use its `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method to grab the `ServletContext` and store the path into the application scope for retrieving it later.

Comment: I have no access to request instance in the static block.

Comment: Then you may have to use a `ServletContextListener` and use its `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method to grab the ServletContext and store the path into the application scope for retrieving it later.

Comment: Actually your last comment is what I needed. If you make it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @OleksandrBondarenko edited the answer with the comments included.